# I am getting column "identity_value" is of type byte error while running the corda node

Tags: corda

I am getting **column "identity_value" is of type byte error** while running the Corda node. I am trying to use one existing schema(`party_a_schema`) for one of my cordapp. I have updated the `node.conf` file for that node.
[image: node error]

After basic analysis, I have found that to use a schema over multiple cordapp in Corda open-source platform, we must execute the below DDL statement.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_schema.hibernate_sequence INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 8 CACHE 1 NO CYCLE;
```

At the time of script execution, I am getting this error
[image: Script execution error]

Comment: Corda doesn’t provision Hibernate with a schema namespace setting and a sequence object may be not created, If your PostgresSQL database is hosting multiple schema instances for different Corda nodes, you will need to create a hibernate_sequence sequence object manually for each subsequent schema added after the first instance. When it says hibernate_sequence already exists it looks like the sequence exists. With ref to your identity_value error can u add some node logs as well?

Comment: I have shared the file with you on slack. Please have a look. I am not getting anything from the node's log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above issue has been resolved. This happens when you do a clean deployNodes many times, in which case your node files are deleted (including the truststores,keys,certificates,nodeinfo files) but these are not deleted from the database. Eventually, you corrupt the database with a new entry being added each time you deploy the node, and hence eventually the node does not start properly.

Ideally in production when you deploy, when you deploy your cordapp for the first time all the required tables are created, node info files, identities , certificates etc. Later if you want to make any changes ideally what you do is upgrade your cordapp and perform database migrations (you dont clean up your entire database).

Hence, in development mode when you connect to an external database, whenever you do a clean deployNodes on the terminal also clean up your database.

Comment: Thanks for working on this issue with me. It's really commendable. Going forward, we must take care of cleaning the database as well.